# Functional way to build a matrix from the list in scala

Tags: scala, matrix, vector, functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

I've asked this question on https://users.scala-lang.org/ but haven't got a concrete answer yet. I am given a vector `v` and I would like to construct a matrix `m` based on this vector according to the rules specified below. I would like to write the following code in a purely functional way, i.e. `m = v.map(...)` or similar. I can do it easily in procedural way like this

```
import scala.util.Random

val v =  Vector.fill(50)(Random.nextInt(100))
println(v)

val m = Array.fill[Int](10, 10)(0)

def populateMatrix(x: Int): Unit = m(x/10)(x%10) += 1

v.map(x => populateMatrix(x))

m foreach { row => row foreach print; println }
```

In words, I am iterating through `v`, getting a pair of indices `(i,j)` from each `v(k)` and updating the matrix `m` at these positions, i.e., `m(i)(j) += 1`. But I am seeking a functional way. It is clear for me how to implement this in, e.g. Mathematica

```
v=RandomInteger[{99}, 300]
m=SparseArray[{Rule[{Quotient[#, 10] + 1, Mod[#, 10] + 1}, 1]}, {10, 10}] & /@ v // Total // Normal
```

But how to do it in scala, which is functional language, too?

Comment: specific link to the question on the users forum: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/making-array-generation-more-functional/8254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your populate matrix approach can be "reversed" - map vector into index tuples, group them, count size of each group and turn it into map (index tuple -> size) which will be used to populate corresponding index in array with `Array.tabulate`:

```scala
val v =  Vector.fill(50)(Random.nextInt(100))
val values = v.map(i => (i/10, i%10))
  .groupBy(identity)
  .view
  .mapValues(_.size)
val result = Array.tabulate(10,10)( (i, j)=> values.getOrElse((i,j), 0))
```